# sklearn.cluster.KMeans got "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_jobs'"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

This error is cause due to following line

```
model = KMeans(n_clusters = k, n_jobs=8, max_iter = iteration).
```

And my sklearn version is 1.0.1. I remember the sklearn.cluster.KMeans has n_jobs parameter. Does the sklearn.cluster.KMeans have no parameter of n-jobs after updating?

Comment: Kmeans doesn't support  `n_jobs` param, see the official [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) for available params.

Comment: `n_jobs` input argument has been deprecated after 0.24.2 version I think. In the latest version there is no such input argument @Fool

Answer (score 4):

If you search for "sklearn kmeans", then the first result will be this official documentation page:

- [sklearn.cluster.KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

On that page, the first thing is the prototype, with the arguments and their default values:

```py
sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, *, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, tol=0.0001, verbose=0, random_state=None, copy_x=True, algorithm='auto')
```

No, there is no argument called `n_jobs`.

There used to be an argument called `n_jobs`, but it was deprecated in version 0.23, and is now removed: [sklearn (0.24) .cluster.KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

Comment: It used to exist some versions before: https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html?highlight=kmeans#sklearn.cluster.KMeans

Answer (score 3):

`n_jobs` input argument has been deprecated after 0.23 version. In the latest version, there is no such input argument.

**Currently, it uses all cores by default.** If you want to use a specific number of cores, you can set the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable (see details) or use the threadpoolctl package. [Source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17276)

From the documentation:

```
n_jobsint, default=None

The number of OpenMP threads to use for the computation. Parallelism is sample-wise on the main cython loop which assigns each sample to its closest center.

None or -1 means using all processors.

Deprecated since version 0.23: n_jobs was deprecated in version 0.23 and will be removed in 1.0 (renaming of 0.25).
```

Source: https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html?highlight=kmeans#sklearn.cluster.KMeans